# How to print taxonomy term field in node.html.twig?

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 7 we use following snippet to print taxonomy term field in node.tpl.php

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($node->field_example['und'][0]['tid']);

$result = field_view_field('taxonomy_term',$term,'field_desired_field');

echo render($result);
```

In Drupal 8 how we can print taxonomy term field in node.html.twig?

Comment: Drupal 8 uses twig instead of templates. To print a variable we use {{  }} and to validate something, we use {% if condition %}.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the field value from a field in a taxonomy term that is referenced in the node:

```
{{ node.field_example.entity.field_desired_field.value }}
```

If you want to render a formatted output, use either the ui to configure a custom view mode or use the module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak):

```
{% set tid = node.field_example.target_id %}
{% if tid %}
  {{ drupal_field('field_desired_field', 'taxonomy_term', tid) }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: many thanks. this works fine for me and please how can i print image field please.

Comment: Normally you configure an image field in ui. If you want to do this in twig see the 5th example on the linked page from Twig Tweak.

Comment: If my tanonomy field named as: "field_kategorie", it must be the "field_example"? But what is the "field_desired_field"?

Comment: @FrankGiesecke, the second field is the field you want to print in the targeted taxonomy term.

Comment: ? That means the same field in my example? Sorry, I don't understand it

Comment: No, these are two separate fields in different entities. You have to read the question, the first field is a node field, which references a taxonomy term and this has it's own set of fields and you want to print one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest equivalent is described here [Rendering arbitrary field values without a parent entity in Drupal 8](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/115117/rendering-arbitrary-field-values-without-a-parent-entity-in-drupal-8) and a core issue to make it more reasonable is [#2274169 EntityViewBuilder::viewField() / viewFieldItem()](https://www.drupal.org/node/2274169) don't work for arbitrary added field values

Comment: This issue does not apply here, because the field has a parent entity.

Answer (score -2):

In drupal 8, you can do it as -

`{% if node.hasField('field_TAXONOMY-TERM') == true %}
   {{ node.field_TAXONOMY-TERM.value }}
  {% endif %}`

Comment: He means the field that is inside the taxonomy term, not the term name.