# Print field of taxonomy term in twig

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have a taxonomy term called Event type. Inside that term I have a Color field. I want to pass the HEX value of the Color field as a variable in Twig.

The taxonomy term variable in Twig (on node level) looks something like this

```
{{ content.field_event_type }}
```

So in order to access the field that exists inside that term, I would need something like this

```
{{ content.field_event_type.field_color_field.value }}
```

But I can't seem to make it work.

How do I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to print taxonomy term field in node.html.twig?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223152/how-to-print-taxonomy-term-field-in-node-html-twig)

Comment: Swap `content` for `node` and add `entity`: `{{ node.field_event_type.entity.field_color_field.value }}`.

Comment: @leymannx Thanks for answering. I have seen that thread and tried that code, but it's not outputting anything. I double checked that my field contains value. The value of the field is visible on the taxonomy/term/n url page. Don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: That's important info that should be in the post not in comments. You did flush the caches already I guess. Maybe we need to see more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone else having a brain malfunction like me and wanted to print a taxonomy term that had been selected and not 1 specific term like all the other posts, do this:

```
{{ node.field_name.entity.label }}
```